# Is there a real difference between calling a JS EventHandler directly vs via an Anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, anonymous

I've taken over someone else's project, so looking at a lot of code that is written differently then how I would have done it... Before I tweak it, I wanted to be sure I'm not somehow changing the functionality of the code.

So the code in question looks like this:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtFoo" runat="server">
   <ClientSideEvents KeyPress="function(s,e) { ProcessKeyPress(s, e); }" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

I understand that this is an anonymous function that calls a function/method which just happens to take the same params as an event handler (sender and event args).

My question is why? Is there some advantage to the above calling convention? Vs something simpler like this:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtFoo" runat="server">
   <ClientSideEvents KeyPress="ProcessKeyPress" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

AFAIK these functionally achieve the same result. And I would think, at least in theory, my second implementation would be faster (although to such a small degree is wouldn't be noticeable to the user).

Is there something else going on with the first implementation and the anonymous function that I'm not getting?

thanx!

Comment: None of that is standard HTML, I guess it's something specific to ASP.Net.

Comment: If it works and performs well enough, I'd be tempted to leave it alone.

Comment: Oops, I should have mentioned, this is a DevExpress control.